# Embedding a text chunk in the text-area of two or more nodes

Tags: nodes, 9

I wish to embed the same text chunk inside the **text-area** of two or more nodes.

One possible way is to call a node of content type B **inside** the relevant nodes of content type A by HTML `iframe` but iframes have their problems and aren't ideal.

How would you suggest to do that?

Comment: I see you edited your question.  If you just want to show a single text chunk on multiple nodes, the easiest way is to use a block.  However, if you have many such text chunks, you probably want to use an entity reference as described in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How to add a chunk of text in multiple nodes?"

1. Create a custom module and add a custom token to the module that contains the chunk of text.
2. Install the [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) module and enable it for the input filter that you use in your text area.
3. Add the custom token to the text area on the relevant nodes.

Comment: As a non PHP programmer creating a custom module is far from me. Perhaps there is a contrib module that will help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to the original question of "**How to put a node of content type B inside a node of content type A?**"

There are a lot of ways to do this, but the most common is probably an entity reference.

This answer assumes you are using Drupal 9, but roughly the same approach can be followed for Drupal 7.

Add an entity reference field on content type A.

Next, edit each node of content type A that should include content type B, and set the appropriate content type B in the entity reference field.

This establishes a connection between a specific node of content type A and content type B.

To change how content type B is displayed on content type A, you can use view modes.

Create a view mode called something like "entity reference" on content type B, and then configure the display as you wish it to appear on content type A.

Then, on content type A, go to "Manage display" and set "Rendered entity" as the format for the entity reference field.  Click the little gear to the right, and choose the view mode for content type B that you created as an entity reference.

For more complex layouts, you can use Layout Builder to create the view mode, but that's outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: I misunderstand how to *choose the specific node* from Content type B **when inside** the node of content type A

Comment: After you add the entity reference field to content type A, when you are on the edit page of a node of content type A, you will be able to select a node of content type B for the entity reference field.